# Loop breaks when 2 - PHP

Tags: php

This is a very simple script, but it breaks when the slots is exactly 2, for other cases the script runs fine
i cant find the error, plz help !

```
function main()
{
 $slots=$_POST['counter']; //number of slots
 include 'config.php';
 for ($num = 1; $num <= $slots; $num++) //$num starts from 1, not 0
 {
  if (($_FILES["myfile$num"]['type']=='image/jpeg'))
  {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile$num"]['tmp_name'],$albumDir.'\\'.$_FILES["myfile$num"]['name']);
   copy($albumDir.'\\'.$_FILES["myfile$num"]['name'], $albumDir.'_thumb\\'.$_FILES["myfile$num"]['name']);
   resize($_FILES["myfile$num"]['name']);
  }
  else if($_FILES["myfile$num"]['name']!='')
    echo 'Image should be in JPEG/JPG format, and size should not exceed 1 MB';
 }
}
```

Comment: "Breaks" mean the code do not work as intended when the slot value is 2 !

Comment: Which clears up absolutely nothing. What DOES it do when $slots is 2? You say it's the only "bad" case, so what happens then?

Comment: if $slot=2 then file does not get uploaded

Comment: It runs fine for other cases? What are the other cases you use to get it working?

Comment: if ($slot!=2 && $slot>0)  //It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. The following things could be happening:

- Your counter var is different than the real number of uploaded files
- Your filenames arenot exactly the ones you're trying to read.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: yup, the problem was with the same image name !

Answer (score 1):

check whether $_POST['counter'] value set ==2;then u proccedd...

```
    $slots=count($_POST['name']);
 //number of slots
 include 'config.php';
 for ($num = 1; $num <= $slots; $num++) //$num starts from 1, not 0

or
  for ($num = 1; $num < $slots+1; $num++)
 {
         //your code..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

start $num from 0

```
for ($num = 0; $num <= $slots; $num++)
```